# RxJs create observable from the result of other observale

Tags: rxjs, observable

```
    var quakes = Rx.Observable.interval(5000).flatMap(function() {
        return Rx.DOM.jsonpRequest({
            url: QUAKE_URL,
            jsonpCallback: 'eqfeed_callback'
        }).retry(3);
    })
    .flatMap(function(result) {
        return Rx.Observable.from(result.response.features);
    })
    .distinct(function(quake) {
        return quake.properties.code;
    });

quakes.subscribe(function(quake) {
    var coords = quake.geometry.coordinates;
    var size = quake.properties.mag * 10000;
    console.log(1);
    L.circle([coords[1], coords[0]], size).addTo(map);
});
```

I want create observable from the result of quakes, how can i get this? I don't find any method, only idea about creating empty observable and cocan with existing quakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't understand the question in full depth, I can only give you some hints:

Option 1. You can subscribe multiple times at `quakes`, if you want to do different thing with the result.

Option 2. Instead of subscribing and logging the result, you could `map` it instead and subscribe on the new result, e.g.

```
var quakesResult = quakes.map(function(quake) {
    var coords = quake.geometry.coordinates;
    var size = quake.properties.mag * 10000;
    console.log(1);
    return L.circle([coords[1], coords[0]], size);
});
quakesResult.subscribe(...);
```

Option 3. You can use a `Subject` to notify you, when you added the circle in your subscribe method, e.g.

```
var mySubject = new Rx.Subject();
quakes.subscribe(function(quake) {
   var coords = quake.geometry.coordinates;
   var size = quake.properties.mag * 10000;
   console.log(1);
   L.circle([coords[1], coords[0]], size).addTo(map);
   mySubject.onNext();
});
mySubject.subscribe(function() { console.log('was added');});
```

Comment: thanks! second options great for me! I wrire hover method for pop-up details